# Why did an undefined margin arise?

Tags: css

I'm doing clone coding of Lotte World homepage in Korea.The homepage has a layout with the float elements. I gave the logo float property to the left. and I gave the `.info` class float property to the right. And naturally, the `.gnb` class becomes a central alignment. through text-align center. The problem is that there is an undefined margin on top of `.gnb` class. I did some experiments and deleted the logo and the problem was solved. I want to know exactly what caused the problem.

```css
/*no reset css*/

header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 46px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
    background: #f8f8f8;
}

#header::after{
    content:"";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

#header{
    position: relative;
    width: 1173px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header .left li a{
    display: inline-block;
    height: 46px;
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#555;
} 

#header .left li{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 20px;
    line-height: 46px;
}

/* 첫 번째 자식 구분선 해제 */

#header .left li:first-child{
    padding-left: 0;
}

#header .left li:first-child:after{
    display: none;
}

/* 로고 구분선 */

#header .left li:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 14px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #e1e1e1;
}

/* 왼쪽 로고 이미지 */

#header .left li:first-child a{
    padding: 0 0 0 28px;
    background: url('https://adventure.lotteworld.com/common/images/icon/header_sky_icon.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

#header .left li:nth-child(2) a{
    padding: 0 0 0 35px;
    background: url('https://adventure.lotteworld.com/common/images/icon/header_aqua_icon.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

#header .left li:last-child a{
    padding: 0 0 0 33px;
    background: url('https://adventure.lotteworld.com/common/images/icon/header_water_icon.png') no-repeat 0 50%;
}

/* 오른쪽 */

.family,
.members,
.lang{
    display: inline-block;
}
#header .right{
    float: right;
}

#header .right li,
a{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 46px;
}

#header .family > a:last-child{
    padding-right: 30px;
}

#header .family a:hover{
    color: #590fe4;
}

#header .members a:hover{
    color: #000;
}

#header .members a,
#header .lang a{
    font-weight: bold;
}

#header .family a,
#header .members a{
    padding: 0 11px;
}

#header .family a,
#header .members a,
#header .lang a{
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #555;
}

#header .family li:first-child:after,
#header .members li:first-child:after{
    display: none;
}

#header .family li:after,
#header .members li:after{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 14px;
    width: 1px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #e1e1e1;
}

#header .lang a{
    padding-right: 16px;
    height: 46px; 
    background: url('img/lang_arrow.png') no-repeat right center;
}

/* 네비게이션 */

nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 99px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e1e1e1;
}

#nav{
    width: 1173px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

/* 왼쪽 */

#nav h1{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 13px;
}

/* 중앙 */

#nav .gnb::before{
    content:"";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

#nav .gnb{
    float: left;
    height: 99px;
    margin-left: 176px;
}

#nav .gnb li:first-child{
    padding-left: 0;
}

#nav .gnb li{
    height: 99px;
    padding-left: 48px;
    float: left;
}

#nav .gnb li a{
    display: block;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 95px;
}

/* 오른쪽 */

#nav .info{
    height: 78px;
    margin-top: 21px;
    float: right;
}

#nav .info .srch, .reser, .group{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 32px;
    float: left;
}

#nav .info .Btn span{
    display: block;
}

#nav .info .Btn span:nth-child(2){
    padding-top: 13px;
}

#nav .info .txt{
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #590fe4;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ko">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>롯데월드 어드벤처</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="img/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div id="header">
            <ul class="left">
                <li><a href="#">SEOUL SKY</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">롯데월드 아쿠아리움</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">김해롯데워터파크</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="right">
                <div class="family">
                    <li><a href="#">민속박물관</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">아이스링크</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class="members">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">회원가입</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="lang">
                    <a href="#">KOR</a>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </header>
    <nav>
        <div id="nav">
            <h1>
                <a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="롯데월드 어드벤처 로고"></a>
            </h1>
            <ul class="gnb">
                <li><a href="#">즐길거리</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">요금/우대혜택</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">참여프로그램</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">이용가이드</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">소통서비스</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="info">
                <p class="srch Btn">
                    <span>
                        <img src="img/header_srch_btn.png" alt="검색하기">
                    </span>
                    <span class="txt">검색</span>
                </p>
                <p class="reser Btn">
                    <span>
                        <img src="img/reser_btn.png" alt="예매하기">
                    </span>
                    <span class="txt">예매</span>
                </p>
                <p class="group Btn">
                    <span><img src="img/group_btn.png" alt="단체예약"></span>
                    <span class="txt">단체</span>
                </p>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most Browsers render a default margin for ordered and unordered lists. To avoid that use reset css rules (for example [this](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/))

## EDIT

actually you set the margin youself here:

```css
#nav .gnb{
    float: left;
    height: 99px;
    margin-left: 176px; // remove this line
}
```

Comment: I'm using it T^T